# Funky Fundamental Group Question

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $D$ be a closed disk (w/ boundary $C$) and let $D_a$, $D_b$ be two disjoint closed disks in the interior of $D$ (w/ boundaries $C_a$ and $C_b$, resp.) . Now remove the interiors of $D_a$ and $D_b$, and identify the points on $C_a$ that are 90 degrees apart, the points on $C_b$ that are 120 degrees apart, and the points on $C$ that are 180 degrees apart (antipodal identification).

What is the fundamental group of this resulting space?

I know that the fundamental group depends only on the 2-skeleton, and that if I have for example a circle and I attach a 2-cell via a map of degree $m$ then I will end up w/ a 2-complex w/ fundamental group $\mathbb{Z_m}$. And if I attach another 2-cell via a map of degree $n$ then I will end up w/ a 2-complex w/ fundamental group $\mathbb{Z_{(m,n)}}$. I am having trouble applying this or a similar type of reasoning here though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to look at it is to start with the wedge sum of three circles, each representing one of $C$, $C_a$, $C_b$. Let $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1) = \langle x, y, z \rangle$, the free group on three generators. The space you have results from this wedge sum by attaching a $2$-cell along $x^2y^3z^4$. Therefore, the fundamental group of the given space is
$$
\langle x, y, z \mid x^2y^3z^4 \rangle.
$$

Of course, you can still apply Van Kampen. It will give you the same result as long as you handle the inclusion map right. When the generator of the fundamental group of intersection is mapped into each subspace, it's mapped to multiples of generators according to identification.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be hard to compute by using Van-Kampen's theorem: consider an open disk which includes $D_a \cup D_b$ and the complement of a smaller disk still containing $D_a \cup D_b$.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, so if I let $A_1=$ the disk containing $D_a \cup D_b$ and $A_2=$ the complement of a smaller disk containing $D_a \cup D_b$, then my total space $X= A_1 \cup A_2$ and $A_1 \cap A_2= S^1$, so by Van- Kampen, $\pi_1(X)\cong (\pi_1(A_1)*\pi_1(A_2))/\pi_1(S^1)$? Now, $\pi_1(A_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ ( since it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP^2}$-a point in the 2-cell. Still figuring out fund group of $A_1$...

Comment: Oh, I guess I can just use Van Kampen again to get $\pi_1(A_1)=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$. So $\pi_1(X)=(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}= \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Use a presentation, you get $\pi_1(X)=<x,y,z:x=y*z>=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Lano, could I ask you to expand a little bit on that last comment? I am not too comfortable w/ amalgamated products yet... Thanks.

Comment: To compute fundamental groups, hence often non abelian, it is useful to use generators and relation. Writing $<x,y,z:x=y*z>$ means that you are considering the quotient of  $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ by the normal subgroup generated by $x*(y*z)^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't think this is right. You don't take into account identifications. When the generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$ (the intersection) is mapped via inclusion, it's not mapped to generators, but multiples of generators because of identification.

Comment: Of course, you're right and I have been too hasty. The right presentation is $<x,y,z: x=y^4 * z^3>$.